# Farmstead Inventory

Tags: everyday-life, agriculture

I'm looking for an inventory of the principal goods, buildings, livestock, and workers of a European farmstead; preferably before 1000 AD.

I know I've seen a primary source document like this before.  It may have been for a Roman villa, which would be just fine.

Comment: What culture are you looking for?

Comment: @Luke, any European one would be fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a source request.